# Drag from dataview and drop in panel in extjs4

Tags: extjs, drag-and-drop, extjs4

I am creating a drag and drop where i have a dataview with a set of images. Then i have a panel where i want to let the user drop the images from the dataview. Using the examples in the sencha examples i was able to get something like this. But i am getting an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'afterValidDrop' of undefined
```

This is what i have in my panel.

```
Ext.define('Memegen.view.MemeBuildArea',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.memebuildarea',
    listeners: {
        render: initializeMemeDropZone
    },
    cls: 'meme-target',
});

function initializeMemeDropZone(targetPanel) {  
    targetPanel.dropTarget = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropTarget', targetPanel.el);
    targetPanel.dropTarget.notifyDrop = function(source, evt, data) {
    if(typeof console != "undefined")
      console.log("notifyDrop:" + source.id);
    var droppedPanel = Ext.getCmp(source.id);

    droppedPanel.dd.afterValidDrop = function() {
      targetPanel.add(droppedPanel.cloneConfig({
        draggable: false,
        title: "Can't Drag This Panel."
      }));
      droppedPanel.destroy();
    };
    return true;
}

  targetPanel.dropTarget.notifyEnter = function(source, evt, data) {
    if(typeof console != "undefined")
      console.log("notifyEnter:" + source.id);
    return this.callParent(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };

  targetPanel.dropTarget.notifyOut = function(source, evt, data) {
    if(typeof console != "undefined")
      console.log("notifyOut:" + source.id);
    return this.callParent(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };

  targetPanel.dropTarget.notifyOver = function(source, evt, data) {
    if(typeof console != "undefined")
      console.log("notifyOver:" + source.id);
    return this.callParent(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  };

}
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In order for the dd property to be defined, your panel needs to be draggable (see API documentation of Ext.panel.Panel, draggable config).